# New to selenium and trying to take a token from request header in java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Having an external website like example.com which contains login page and after logged in it will redirect to some example.com/user. From this /user route, need to take token info from one request header. Automated with selenium for first page to login but once I reach to the /user with some wait condition also, the request header is not being captured. Also is it possible to capture all request headers like cookies etc? Please suggest best way to handle and take the token from request header

```
        driver = new EdgeDriver();
        DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
        devTools.createSession();
        driver.get("https://example.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(80));  
        WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("example-signin-username"));
        email.sendKeys("1234");
        
        WebElement pwd = driver.findElement(By.id("example-signin-password"));
        pwd.sendKeys("App");
        
        WebElement loginBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("example-signin-submit"));
        loginBtn.click();
        
        devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.of(1000000), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()));
        devTools.addListener(Network.requestWillBeSent(), request -> {
            System.out.println("Request Method : " + request.getRequest().getMethod());
            System.out.println("Request URL : " + request.getRequest().getUrl());
            System.out.println("Request headers: " + request.getRequest().getHeaders().toString());
            System.out.println("Request body: " + request.getRequest().getPostData().toString());
        });
        
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains("user"));
```

[image: Values required from req headers in browser]